# Thymeleaf - How to add checked attribute to input conditionally

Tags: html, thymeleaf, html-input

As you know, `input` component has an attribute, `checked` to whether mark the checkbox as enabled by default or not.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" checked="checked"/>
```

To disable the checkbox by default, the `checked` exception should be declared. Is it possible to set `checked` attribute by a flag in Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

According to the official thymeleaf documentation

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes

`th:checked` is considered as a fixed-value Boolean attribute.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="active" th:checked="${user.active}" />
```

Where `user.active` should be a `boolean`.

So in your case it should be as *Andrea* mentioned,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" th:checked="${flag}" />
```

Comment: Does checkbox not work with th:field attribute? I am adding th:field and everytime the backend receives the value as false?

Answer (score 8):

After digging a little, I found out the solution. There is `th:checked` attribute for that purpose.

This works:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" th:checked="${flag} ? 'checked'">
```

This fails:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckbox" th:checked="${flag} ? 'checked' : ''">
```

If `checked=""` is set to `input` component, it's marked checked. This method is valid for custom attributes`th:attr` also. Consider following example:

```
<p th:attr="customattr=${flag}?'attr'></p>
```

If `flag` is true, it's replaced with:

```
<p customattr="attr"></p>
```

If `flag` is false, it's replaced with:

```
<p></p>
```

Comment: simply `th:checked=${flag}`, is more concise for checked attribute

Comment: @Andrea is it possible to do a comparison i.e. `th:checked="${model.myField == null}"` ?

Comment: how to i set flag as true?

Comment: Flag is set in request handler, in a class like `UserController`` @Jesse

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally add checked attribute to radio input in thymeleaf as below:

```
 <input type="radio" th:checked="${sales.sales_head.sales_type} == CREDIT" class="sales_type" value="CREDIT"  name="sales_type" >
```

Here if sales_type is CREDIT the radio will be checked. Otherwise it remains unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Thymeleaf `th:checked` attribute is fixed-value attribute and it does not toggle the boolean value on checking or unchecking the box.

To toggle the boolean value for backend use, use '`th:field` attribute with the syntax: `th:field="${object.attribute}"`

A working code snippet that i used in my project is given here as exmple:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/editNotificationAlerts}" th:object="${userObject}" method="post">

      <label for="sendEmailNotification">Notify At 80</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sendEmailNotification" id="sendEmailNotification" th:field="${userObject.sendEmailNotification}">

<div>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>

</form>
```

The toggled value shall be passed to controller on submit action.

Answer (score 0):

Neither suggested solutions worked for me.

This one worked:

```
th:checked="${#strings.equals(param.myRequestParameterXYZ, 'foobar')}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced problem for showing checkbox (tick mark on/off) in thymeleaf based on true or false value for the property. I solved it by following way.

Method in controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String showCheckbox(Model model) {
 boolean myBooleanVariable = false;
 model.addAttribute("myBooleanVariable", myBooleanVariable);
 return "sample-checkbox";
}
```

In HTML page:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="myBooleanVariable" th:checked="${myBooleanVariable}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form that is a model representation, say foo, and bar is a checkbox on your form and property of foo (e.g. foo.bar):

```
<form th:object="${foo}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{bar}" th:value="*{bar}"></input>
</form>
```

...will also work and presents a succinct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Logical and / or conditions with it like

```
th:checked="${business?.status == true or business?.status == null}"
```