# Boolean attribute not binding in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am trying to get my checkbox marked by setting an attribute of a model to true, but it does not get checked. This is my checkbox:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <input type="hidden" value="on" name="_abroad"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="abroad" onchange="getAbroad(this)"
           th:checked="${abroad} ? 'checked'"/>
    <span>Abroad</span>
</div>
```

and this is my model where I set my abroad property to true and the corresponing object I am adding to my model:

controller:

```
cityWrapper.setAbroad(true);
model.addAttribute("city", cityWrapper);
```

my wrapper:

```
public class CityWrapper {

    private List<City> cityList;
    private boolean abroad;
}
```

Comment: If the form bound to the city object?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it through the city object (set by the controller):

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <input type="hidden" value="on" name="_abroad"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="abroad" onchange="getAbroad(this)"
           th:checked="${city.abroad}"/>
    <span>Abroad</span>
</div>
```

Please also refer to:
[Thymeleaf - How to add checked attribute to input conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826576/thymeleaf-how-to-add-checked-attribute-to-input-conditionally)