# value of HTML element is undefined but it is set

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I want to set checkbox after the page has renderet to the matching state of the backend.

I implemented this function for that purpose what does the job so far

**Updated to user-suggestion** It doesn't matter if cbs[i].dataset.thvalue or cbs[i].dataset.value

```
 function updateCheckboxes () {

  let activeCheckbox = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClickOnReduce()" checked>'
  let inactiveCheckbox = '<input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClickOnReduce()">'

  let cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
  for (let i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].id === 'reduceCheckbox' || cbs[i].id === 'slCheckbox') {
      if (cbs[i].dataset.thvalue === 'true') {
        cbs[i].innerHTML = activeCheckbox
      }
      else {
        cbs[i].innerHTML = inactiveCheckbox
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML part, using Thymeleaf

```
    <td id="reduceCheckbox" data-th-value="${car.isReduced()}"></td>
    <td id="slCheckbox" data-th-value="${car.isSl()}"></td>
```

But the browser claims by printing out the value, that it is undefined, even if the value is set as you can see in the picture live from the browser.

[image]

Due to the docu my syntax should be correct?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp

Any suggestion?

Ty

Comment: Why not this way? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29925235/5138198

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like my misunderstanding of the Thymeleaf syntax with regards to th-data led to that issue.

This is the fix:

```
<td id="reduceCheckbox" th:attr="data-value=${car.isReduced()}"></td>
```

Access via

```
 console.log(cbs[i].dataset.value)
```

Answer (score 11):

You HTML is invalid.

`<td>` elements do not have `value` attributes. (The link you reference is talking about `<option>`, not `<td>`).

Your browser is not mapping the JS `value` property onto your invented attribute.

If you want to add arbitrary data to an element, use a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and read it using the [dataset API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I tried and updated my code, still have the same issue :-/

Comment: When you hyphenate data (i.e. data-th-value), you need to camel case (capitalise each word after the first) to reference. Thus, you should reference: `cbs[i].dataset.thValue` NOT `cbs[i].dataset.thvalue`

Answer (score 0):

**value** is not valid attributes in **td** tag. you can use **abbr** attributes

`<td id="reduceCheckbox" abbr="true">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClickOnReduce()">
    </td>`

then you can get it

```
console.log(cbs[i].abbr)
```

Note: The abbr attribute is not supported in HTML5.

For **HTML5** you can use **headers** attributes

```
<td id="reduceCheckbox" headers="true">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClickOnReduce()">
</td>
```

then you can get it

```
console.log(cbs[i].headers)
```