# Thymeleaf checkbox can't default to checked when using th:field?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Does anyone know how to add a default setting of `checked` in a Thymeleaf, SpringBoot, Java project, to an input field for a Single checkbox?
I have to use `th:field` because I am later submitting this form via email and if I use `th:name` with the checked box default, the default works but email doesn't.

Any suggestions?

```
<label>
       <input type="checkbox" id="serviceLevel"  th:field="*{serviceLevel}" th:checked="${serviceLevel}"/>
Affiliate Serviced</label>
```

Email html code to pull value on email:

```
<tr class="emailRow">
  <h3>Direct: </h3>
    <td class="bodycopy" th:text="${directBind.directBox}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have this variable set as private Boolean directBox in the model.

I've tried everything: `th:checked=checked`, `value=true`, `value=checked`, set the value and `checked ="${directBox}"` none of this works.

Is there a solution out there?

Comment: If you want to use `th:field`, you might need to change your controller. See this thread: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/The-checked-attribute-of-the-checkbox-is-not-set-in-th-each-td3043675.html

Comment: Do you know if I don't use th:field (and th:name instead), how I can get th:text to send the value via email ? All of my other form elements are th:field, and on the email helper I have it as th:text to read each input's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf - How to add checked attribute to input conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29826576/thymeleaf-how-to-add-checked-attribute-to-input-conditionally)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to use th:field and have it default to checked. Have to set it in my controller, like Gustavo mentioned. Code example below.

```
...
directBind.setDirectBox(true);
directBind.setServiceLevel(true);
model.addAttribute("directBind", directBind);
return "directBind";
```